# How can I set hotkey for "Dash home" -> "search" input field in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hotkeys

I want to launch "Dash home" -> "search" input field by customized key binding in Ubuntu 12.04.

I installed `xbindkeys`, `xbindkeys-config` and `xvkbd` by following this instruction.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts

But I don't know how can I launch the search input field by command. So I could not bind the key and function.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-ubuntu-unity-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to set my own keyboard shortcuts. In the page explains only "default" shortcuts, isn't it?